# ORACLE REGEXP_INSTR No termina

Tags: oracle

Tengo un problema al ejecutar la siguiente instruccion y es que no termina, alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema (tambien ocurre con REGEXP_LIKE y sin  NVL).

```sql
SELECT
NVL(REGEXP_INSTR('(HTTP 500) - soapenv:ServerOSB-382500: OSB Service Callout action received SOAP Fault responseOSB-382500OSB Service Callout action received SOAP Fault responsesoapenv:Server(CM1-000559) Stop collection treatment is not allowed on this account.amdocs.csm3g.exceptions.CMValidateException: (CM1-000559) Stop collection treatment is not allowed on this account.StopCollectionPipelinePairNoderequest-ac42ea5.N370c41ec.0.153414147d5.N7967StopCollectionTreatmrntServiceCalloutStagerequest-pipeline; nested',
'(\r|\n|.)*\(HTTP 500\) \- soapenv\:ServerOSB\-382500(.*)\(CM1\-000559\) Stop collection treatment is not allowed on this(\r|\n|.)*'), 0) indexf
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Cuentanos un poco que quieres conseguir o cual es el resultado que esperas con esa consulta

Comment: Pues que termine, lleva 24hrs y no termina es decir se queda trabado.